# How to get recurring data from an Oracle row using an unique regular expression on it?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

My requirement is to have a regular expression where my data opens with a single tag, but has multiple closing tags

The column data in table looks like:

> %tag1%
> %data1%%tag2%
> %data2%%tag2%
> %data3%%tag2%

I tried /g in my regex for global search but it didn't seem to work.

My oracle query looks like this:

```
select regexp_substr(column_data, '(%tag1%)(.+?)%tag2%',1,1,'n')) from table;
```

I want to get data1, data2 and data3 from the table in three different rows.

Important thing here is that the regular expression has to recursively parse the second tag.

> %tag1% (get this data) %tag2%
>
> %tag1% ... %tag2% (get this data) %tag2%
>
> %tag1% ... %tag2% ... %tag2% (get this data) %tag2%
>
> .. and so on...

I am only able to get the first occurrence.

Can anyone help me get this data in a single select query? Thanks.

Comment: You have a colon in the pattern but not in the input data.

Comment: Sorry it came by mistake. Correcting it.

Comment: Given that there are a number of accepted standards for passing data around (JSON, XML, CSV, etc) It is depressing that anybody would invest their energy in inventing another one. Although maybe this is a college assignment?

Comment: Nope, it's just a dataset I came across in my personal project.